# Allure Report - Do not mark tests as flaky

Tags: allure

I would like to disable marking tests as flaky in the allure report that is generated using the command line. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways your test is marked as flaky:

1. You marked it as flaky explicitly (using tag or something, depends on your language)
2. Your test is set to be rerun after failure

If you encountered with the second case and you don't want to switch rerun off then there is no solution for you out of the box. Allure will mark your test as flaky.